# Need help on creating a script for output files size to a text file

Tags: powershell

i want to create a script that will output the size of 3 files to a text file. and that the sizes will be shown in GB's. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Get-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item?view=powershell-7.3) and [Export-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7.3) cmdlet you could use something like this:

```
    # files to check for size
$files = @(
"C:\Users\JohnDoe\file1.txt",
"C:\Users\JohnDoe\file2.txt",
"C:\Users\JohnDoe\file3.txt"
)
    # path where results will be written
$export = "C:\Users\JohnDoe\list.txt"

foreach ($file in $files) {
        # create suiting object
    $output = "" | select "SizeGB", "Name"
        # get item information
    $item = Get-Item -Path $file
        # transfer size to GB with 2 decimals and write into object
    $output.SizeGB = [math]::round($item.Length/1GB,2)
        # write name into object
    $output.Name = $item.Name
        #export into csv
    $output | Export-csv $export -Append -NoTypeInformation
}
```

The output would be in csv style and look like this:

```
"SizeGB","Name"
"0.06","file1.txt"
"0.09","file2.txt"
"0.04","file3.txt"
```